# How to call Api Url in android?

Tags: android, android-webservice

I am new in android development. I want  to call Api Url in android Studio. I am not able to  call api url in android please help

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried so far.

Comment: No one can help you because of too short description of your problem. Provide proper description of your problem and tried code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark since I don't know what you are trying to do. Here is an AsyncTask command I used called SendArrival.java:

SendArrival.java

```
package company.com.mirrorandroid.commands;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import company.com.mirrorandroid.model.Model;


public class SendArrival extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

    private Context context;

    public SendArrival(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer success) {
        Log.d("Mirror", "finished " + success.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... Void) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://foo.com/arrive");
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("foo.com/arrive");

            try {
                SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(Model.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceId", "12345"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("guestName", sp.getString("guestName","Android Man")));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", sp.getString("message","Better than iOS")));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("memberType", sp.getString("memberType","Green")));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("handle", sp.getString("handle","no-handle from Android")));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                Log.d("mirror", response.toString());
                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200){
                    Log.d("mirror", "error occurred " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
                    return 0;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("mirror", "Send Arrival client prototcol error " + e.toString());
                return 0;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("mirror", "Send Arrival  io error " + e.toString());
                return 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("sp", e.getMessage());
            return 0;
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Then you can invoke it from your activity like this:

```
new SendArrival(context).execute();
```

Like the other commenters, give some more details and we can help you.